# Laravel 3 Query Strings

Tags: laravel, laravel-3, laravel-routing

How can I get ? queries from url? input::all not works.

my route :

```
Route::get('category/(:any?)','category@index');
```

what I wanted to get is like :

```
http://url.com/category/examplecategory?list_as=grid&price_range=2
```

prinr_r of Input::all(). why can't I have list_as => grid and price_range => 2

```
Array ( [category/examplecategory] => )
```

my output should be :

```
Array ( [list_as] => "grid" , [price_range] => 2 [another_filter] => "another value"....)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
parse_str(Request::getQueryString(), $getVars);

// Use these as
echo $getVars['list_as'];
echo $getVars['price_range'];
```

Here, `Request::getQueryString()` (it's method of `symfony` Request class) will return a `query string` and `parse_str` will build the array and will put it into `$getVars`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more feedback as to what you require, and your desired output.

Will your GET data be parsed against a query to return a dataset?

To produce a URL http://url.com/category/examplecategory/grid/2

**Example:**

```
Route::get('category/{examplecategory}/{listas}/{pricerange}', array(function($tripCode) {

    $data = Model::FUNCTION_QUERY($examplecategory,$listas,$pricerange); // these are the values passed in the SEO friendly URL 

    return View::make('categoryview/')->with("data", $data)

}));
```

This essentially uses the URL above, passes the data to a model which returns a dataset in $data, this then is passed into a view called categoryview with all the data which is then processed. I hope this helps a little?

If you want to use posts data try this:

```
Route::get('category/{examplecategory}', array(function($tripCode) {
    $postsdata = Input::all();

    $data = Model::FUNCTION_QUERY($examplecategory,$postdata); // these are the values passed in the SEO friendly URL 

    return View::make('categoryview/')->with("data", $data)

}));
```

Comment: Can't I just use my route as is and get queries starts with ? because its not limited just with listas and pricerange. There are tons of filters.

Comment: Yes you can, You can use the $data = Input::all();